# Triangular Wave Current input to a capactior, Voltage Response?

Tags: capacitor, current, wave

I am simulating a cap. When i give a triangular current input to a capacitor, I see an increase in voltage for both rising and falling side of current signal. why is this happening?

For a rising ramp I(t)=(kt), Voltage is kt^2/2
For a falling ramp I(t)= -(kt), voltage is -kt^2/2

But for a triangular wave, why is it an increasing voltage? it should decrease right?

Please help me understand

Comment: This is unclear. If current ramps linearly how can it also vary quadratically. What is the difference between what you're calling "I(t)" and what you're calling "current"?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say voltage, not current, I edited the question. V(t)=1/Kt^2 and K +ve for Rising Ramp, negative for Falling Ramp. But in simulation, i never see any reversing voltage, its keep on increasing

Comment: \$\frac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}t}=\frac{I}{C}\$, so if I increases (as it does during the ramp) then the rate of change of V must increase.

Comment: V(t)=1/C(Integral of I(t)dt) = 1/2*k*t^2 (ramp I(t) = kt), so for K<0, V(t) should also be negative, that is not happening in simulation

Comment: Are you saying the "I(t) = kt" was defined for t < 0? That's not at all the obvious way to do it. You need to define when the input signal starts and stops. Some graphs would probably help make it clear to us.

Comment: If by triangular you mean that the current is always into the capacitor, it is to be expected that the voltage is always rising.

Comment: Also don't forget every definite integral has a constant of integration...so be clear about what that is when interpreting your results.

Answer (score 2):

You can assume that the rising edge of the triangle as I(t)=k*t and its integral V(t)=(1/2)*t^2.
For the falling edge of the triangle, I(t)=1-K*t and its integral is t-(1/2)*t^2.
You need to add these responses (Applying Superposition and time shifting property of linear circuit principles). 
you get the response as shown in below picture.

Hope this helps.

[image: Plot for Triangular Response]